# Connect to remote SQL server 2012 using visual studio server explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, remote-access

I'm trying to find a good guide for how to make a connection to the remote SQL server (it's 2012 epxress). After some investigation on the interwebs , i couldn't find a decent guide to help me trough this proces.

My setup is like this

On Server

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows SQL server 2012
- Visual Studio 2012
- Team Foundation Server 2012

On Client

- Visual Studio 2010 on client
- Windows SQL server 2012 on client

So my question is , does anyone have a decent guide for me to follow how to connect to a remote server located on my windows 2008 server

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=Connect+to+remote+SQL+server+2012+using+visual+studio+server+explorer

Comment: I tried searching and i always forget to accept the answers on other questions

Comment: @NicolasPierre That's ok - go back and accept any that solved your problem, it's never too late!

Comment: I'm fairly new in the programming world so forgive me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this link for [SQL Server 2008 but it should work for 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

Also, here is a [Q & A](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ab1de11b-502b-4a28-a084-836a2ddf4463) that might give you everything you need:

Comment: i tried the second link but none of the given solutions is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some ways to do that: [Creating Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)